# How to change input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I change my input or make my input ignore some characters like "-" or "|"?
I want to do this because I have a lot of inputs in my projects in different modules and classes.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you mean that remove some characters from a string? Like `input().replace('-', '').replace('|', '')` or `''.join(i for i in input() if i not in '-|')`?

Comment: @KevinGuan No, i need not recognize  that sharacters.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the character:

`cadena = cadena.replace("|", "")`

Comment: What is candena, i think that you dont understand what i need.